# Why I get refused when connect my remote host with domain name using ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, dns, centos, domain

I added two A DNS records on my domain name whose HOSTNAME is `@` and `www`,

I'm wondering why I get refused when use `davidzhu.xyz`

```shell
$ ssh root@davidzhu.xyz 
ssh: connect to host davidzhu.xyz port 22: Connection refused

# This will success
$ ssh root@www.davidzhu.xyz
The authenticity of host 'www.davidzhu.xyz (144.202.12.21)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is...
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working as expected. Both resolve to the same IP

```
dig davidzhu.xyz +short
144.202.12.32

dig www.davidzhu.xyz +short
144.202.12.32
```

ssh works as well

```
~
❯ ssh root@davidzhu.xyz
The authenticity of host 'davidzhu.xyz (144.202.12.32)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:NpOMboPt3497x7ISpCbqOf/oCu4FNMqtzcKQPELZvUw.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'davidzhu.xyz' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
root@davidzhu.xyz's password:


~ took 10s
❯ ssh root@www.davidzhu.xyz
The authenticity of host 'www.davidzhu.xyz (144.202.12.32)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:NpOMboPt3497x7ISpCbqOf/oCu4FNMqtzcKQPELZvUw.
This host key is known by the following other names/addresses:
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:64: davidzhu.xyz
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'www.davidzhu.xyz' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
root@www.davidzhu.xyz's password:
```

My best guess is caching, was pointing to an old/stale IP

Comment: Can you try again now? It seems to me (coming from https://superuser.com/q/1781027/368970) that the domain is now under Cloudflare, maybe you had the old cached from before he added it to Cloudflare (while he had the www cached to also an old IP.)