# Why does my domain name have two IP addresses?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, dns, domain

I use `dig` to check the ip address of my domain on DNS, the output is:

```shell
dig davidzhu.xyz  +short       
172.67.210.8
104.21.50.195
```

But I only have **one** `A DNS record` on my domain, this is the DNS Record of my domain name (the third one is about the google search console):

[image]

And I use cloudflare as my NS, and opened the proxy on cloudflare, cz I use it for free ssl.

[image]

This is my two NS:

```shell
$ dig chin.ns.cloudflare.com +short 
172.64.32.84
173.245.58.84
108.162.192.84

$ dig noel.ns.cloudflare.com +short
108.162.193.216
172.64.33.216
173.245.59.216
```

And I saw [another guy](https://superuser.com/a/1780483/1689666) use `dig` command to check the ip of my domain name `www.davidzhu.xyz`,

```shell
dig davidzhu.xyz +short
144.202.12.32

dig www.davidzhu.xyz +short
144.202.12.32
```

Is this about DNS cache on my mac? I tried to use something like this `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`, but it didn't help.

---

Other info:

```shell
dig www.davidzhu.xyz +trace 

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.davidzhu.xyz +trace
;; global options: +cmd
.           113542  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           113542  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           113542  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           113542  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           113542  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           113542  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           113542  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           113542  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           113542  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           113542  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           113542  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           113542  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           113542  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
;; Received 1097 bytes from 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1) in 6 ms

xyz.            172800  IN  NS  generationxyz.nic.xyz.
xyz.            172800  IN  NS  y.nic.xyz.
xyz.            172800  IN  NS  x.nic.xyz.
xyz.            172800  IN  NS  z.nic.xyz.
xyz.            86400   IN  DS  3599 8 2  
;; Received 678 bytes from 192.33.4.12#53(c.root-servers.net) in 41 ms

davidzhu.xyz.       3600    IN  NS  chin.ns.cloudflare.com.
davidzhu.xyz.       3600    IN  NS  noel.ns.cloudflare.com.
;; Received 585 bytes from 194.169.218.42#53(x.nic.xyz) in 29 ms

www.davidzhu.xyz.   300 IN  A   104.21.50.195
www.davidzhu.xyz.   300 IN  A   172.67.210.8
;; Received 77 bytes from 173.245.59.216#53(noel.ns.cloudflare.com) in 28 ms
```

```shell
$ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            192.168.2.1        UGScg             en0       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS               lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                lo0       
169.254            link#12            UCS               en0      !
192.168.2          link#12            UCS               en0      !
192.168.2.1/32     link#12            UCS               en0      !
192.168.2.1        c:ac:8a:3d:2b:8c   UHLWIir           en0   1182
192.168.2.10       ea:26:6b:65:51:f8  UHLWI             en0   1087
192.168.2.11       56:c5:6d:df:38:e5  UHLWI             en0    369
192.168.2.14       link#12            UHRLWI            en0      !
192.168.2.15/32    link#12            UCS               en0      !
192.168.2.16       5c:87:9c:38:f5:45  UHLWI             en0      !
192.168.2.17       e:a:74:5:69:9      UHLWI             en0      !
192.168.2.18       6c:b1:33:9b:d6:b0  UHLWI             en0    132
192.168.2.19       42:a0:dc:36:87:9a  UHLWI             en0      !
192.168.2.21       94:ea:32:b4:4d:ca  UHLWIi            en0    765
192.168.2.22       94:ea:32:a3:4e:c6  UHLWIi            en0    438
192.168.2.36       link#12            UHRLWI            en0      !
192.168.2.59       link#12            UHRLWI            en0      !
192.168.2.63       link#12            UHRLWI            en0      !
192.168.2.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI            en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#12            UmCS              en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI            en0       
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI            en0       
255.255.255.255/32 link#12            UCS               en0      !
```

---

Thank you guys, and thanks @YisroelTech, I solved this problem by closing the proxy on cloudflare. After I close proxy for `davidzhu.xyz`, then I get just one ip address!

[image]

```
$ dig davidzhu.xyz +trace 
...
...
...
davidzhu.xyz.       3600    IN  NS  chin.ns.cloudflare.com.
davidzhu.xyz.       3600    IN  NS  noel.ns.cloudflare.com.
;; Received 581 bytes from 212.18.249.42#53(generationxyz.nic.xyz) in 26 ms

davidzhu.xyz.       300 IN  A   144.202.12.32
;; Received 57 bytes from 173.245.58.84#53(chin.ns.cloudflare.com) in 34 ms
```

Comment: Does the machine that has a route to `144.202.12.32` have a route to `192.168.2.15`?  One is a internet address the other is a intranet address. It's interesting that your Nameserver is NOT returning `144.202.12.32` which suggest a Nameserver configuration problem.  Within your own network, on the machine that can access `144.202.12.32` are you able to SSH using `192.168.2.15`? You should [edit] your question instead of submitting unformatted comentary

Comment: Im not at my computer, so xhecks from here are difficulr, but a few things to look at/clarify - You ssh to 144.202.12.32,  but your DNS does not resolve to that?   -  You ssh to www.davidzhu.xyz but do ns checks on davidzhu.xyz?   - If you are behind Cloudflare they are likely proxying http and https traffuc from their servers to yours - but when you ssh you want to go directly to your server even though dns will resolve to cloudflare?

Comment: Check the advice in the article [How to Flush DNS Cache in Linux](https://beebom.com/how-flush-dns-cache-linux/).

Comment: The IP for your domain on all DNS servers are indeed the two Cloudflare IPs (see https://dnschecker.org/#A/davidzhu.xyz). Do you use Cloudflare ONLY for DNS or you have set up one of their protections or other services (which would explain why all the traffic would first be routed to them to protect your IP)?

Comment: To summarize what I say, is that your results seems to make sense and match with what it shows on DNS, if something I would have a question why the "other guy" still has the 144.x.x.x IP, maybe he has that cached or otherwise statically set.

Comment: @YisroelTech, I'm not sure, it happened days ago in [another question](https://superuser.com/a/1780483/1689666) I asked. I will check on another computer, but not I only have one computer.

Comment: @Ramhound, No, I checked my routing table on my computer, and I pasted the out put on the detail of question, when I tried to connect `192.168.2.15` with ssh, it connect my localhost, and thank you for your advice for edit question.

Comment: @ShaowenZhu, I bet he still had it cached (BTW in that one you can see that you had something else cached `144.202.12.21` (and not `144.202.12.32`). But to the point here, the reason it is now pointing to Cloudflare's IPs and not your own (and that can be seen across the board by checking https://dnschecker.org/#A/www.davidzhu.xyz) is quite obvious that it's set up to use Cloudflare as protection/proxying, in which case this is expected behavior.

Comment: @ShaowenZhu - So what is the intranet address of the SSH server if it's NOT `192.168.2.15`? I assumed you provided `192.168.2.15` since it was your server intranet IP address

Comment: @Ramhound, `192.168.2.15` is his SSH client IP

Comment: @YisroelTech, Ohhh, It makes sense,  thanks for your reply! I will close the proxy on cloudflare, and try again, thanks agagin!

Comment: please move the solution you found to an answer post (see [answer]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the domain has two IP addresses is that the domain was put under Cloudflare, and the way Cloudflare works is by proxying all your traffic through them (they have the SSL on their system, so it can't go directly to you.)

See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66214163/5518385 that it doesn't seem to be any way around it, this is the way their SSL works (and for free SSL on your own you can use Let's Encrypt etc.)

You can verify the DNS propagation in general by checking with https://dnschecker.org/#A/www.davidzhu.xyz (now shows Cloudflare's two IPs)

(The fact that that other guy had the 144.x.x.x IP is because ***he*** had old cache from before it was added to Cloudflare.)

Comment: Thank you!! I closed proxy for `davidzhu.xyz` on cloudflare, and when I tried `dig davidzhu.xyz` and I get just one desired ip address!!